# Parsing results from HTMLAgiltyPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to parse the Yahoo Finance page for a list of stock symbols and company names. The URL i'm using is: http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFTSE

The code i'm using is;

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument page = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFTSE");

        var titles = page.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='yfnc_tabledata1']");
    // Returns all titles on the home page of this site in an array.

        foreach (var title in titles)
        {
            txtLog.AppendText(title.InnerHtml + System.Environment.NewLine);

        }
```

The txtLog.AppendText line was just me testing. The code correctly gets each lines that contains a class of yfnc_tabledata1 under the node of td. Now when i'm in the foreach loop i need to parse title to grab the symbol and company name from the following HTML;

```
<b><a href="/q?s=GLEN.L">GLEN.L</a></b>
GLENCORE XSTRAT
<b>343.95</b> <nobr><small>3 May 16:35</small></nobr>
<img width="10" height="14" style="margin-right:-2px;" border="0"
src="http://l.yimg.com/os/mit/media/m/base/images/transparent-1093278.png"
class="pos_arrow" alt="Up"> <b style="color:#008800;">12.80</b>
<bstyle="color:#008800;"> (3.87%)</b> 68,086,160
```

Is it possible to parse the results of a parsed document? I'm a little unsure on where to start.

Comment: Have you tried loading the partial html back into an `HtmlDocument`?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to continue some XPATH extraction work from where you are. There are many possibilities. The difficulty is all the yfnc_tabledata1 nodes are at the same level. Here is how you can do it (in a console app example it will dump the list of symbols and companies):

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument page = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFTSE");

// get directly the symbols under the 1st TD element. Recursively search for an A element that has an HREF attribute under this TD.
var symbols = page.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='yfnc_tabledata1']//a[@href]");

foreach (var symbol in symbols)
{
    // from the current A element, go up two level and get the next TD element.
    var company = symbol.SelectSingleNode("../../following-sibling::td").InnerText.Trim();
    Console.WriteLine(symbol.InnerText + ": " + company);
}
```

More on XPATH axes here: [XPATH Axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)